# golang http client idle with https

Tags: go, httpclient

i have a test for http client idle, if i run it, i always get idle conn by https conn.
the log is below.

```
=== RUN   TestWithOneClient2
work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc0000a8058 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49356 => 58.250.137.36:80
work1 PutIdleConn: <nil>
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc00006e000 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49357 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false
work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc000010050 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49358 => 58.250.137.36:80
work1 PutIdleConn: <nil>
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc00006e000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:1.069584516s} ,172.26.33.1:49357 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false

work2 start
work2 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc0000a8020 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49359 => 35.170.21.246:80
work2 resp.Proto: HTTP/1.1 false
work2 PutIdleConn: <nil>

work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc000136000 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49360 => 58.250.137.36:80
work1 PutIdleConn: <nil>
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc00006e000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:2.582808258s} ,172.26.33.1:49357 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false
--- PASS: TestWithOneClient2 (5.46s)
PASS
```

it looks like a `302` for http to https request. why the ilde conn is `https` but not is the last conn?

the test code is below, in code i want try connect reuse for http request.

```
package learn_http

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"
    "net/url"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func gotConn(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
    fmt.Printf("work1 Connection reused for %+v ,%+v => %+v\n", info, info.Conn.LocalAddr(),info.Conn.RemoteAddr())
}
func worker1(client *http.Client) {
    fmt.Println(`work1 start`)
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: gotConn,
        PutIdleConn: func(err error) {
            fmt.Println("work1 PutIdleConn:", err)
        },
    }
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://www.qq.com/")
    req := &http.Request{
        URL:    u,
        Method: "GET",
    }
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)

    fmt.Println("work1 resp.Proto:", resp.Proto,resp.Close)
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}

func gotConn2(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
    fmt.Printf("work2 Connection reused for %+v ,%+v => %+v\n", info, info.Conn.LocalAddr(),info.Conn.RemoteAddr())
}
func worker2(client *http.Client) {
    fmt.Println(`work2 start`)
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: gotConn2,
        PutIdleConn: func(err error) {
            fmt.Println("work2 PutIdleConn:", err)
        },
    }
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://httpbin.org/get")
    req := &http.Request{
        URL:    u,
        Method: "GET",
    }
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Println("work2 resp.Proto:", resp.Proto,resp.Close)
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}

func TestWithOneClient2(t *testing.T) {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns: 1,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 1,
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
    }
    worker1(client)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    worker1(client)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    fmt.Println()
    worker2(client)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    fmt.Println()
    worker1(client)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
}
```

i find if i change the `work1` request url is `https://www.qq.com` it works like below.

```
=== RUN   TestWithOneClient2
work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc0000a2000 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49383 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false
work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc0000a2000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:1.005156698s} ,172.26.33.1:49383 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false

work2 start
work2 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc00009e020 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s} ,172.26.33.1:49384 => 3.221.81.55:80
work2 resp.Proto: HTTP/1.1 false
work2 PutIdleConn: <nil>

work1 start
work1 Connection reused for {Conn:0xc0000a2000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:2.491818827s} ,172.26.33.1:49383 => 58.250.137.36:443
work1 resp.Proto: HTTP/2.0 false
--- PASS: TestWithOneClient2 (5.03s)
PASS
```

it looks always reuse https conn?

add question.

i read the code `http/transport.go`
https connect got from  `cc, err := t.connPool().GetClientConn(req, addr)`
and
http connect got from `idleConn     map[connectMethodKey][]*persistConn` 
There seems to be no influence between them。
but why it can not reuse last http connect.

Comment: "Why the ilde conn is https but not is the last conn?" Can you try to re-phrase that question? I really can't make out what you're trying to ask. "It looks always reuse https conn?" Yes. Is that surprising to you? If so, why?

Comment: i  reedit it. I wonder why  it can't reuse HTTP connect? @Peter

Comment: I'm going to read the code more carefully. @Peter